# Unable to understand Export in Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules

While I was exporting functions from one folder in Node.js, I encountered some ambiguity.

**Export Statement:**

```
function getPosts(req, res){
    res.send("Server is Running");
}
export { getPosts };
```

**Import Statement:**

```
import express from "express";
import { getPosts } from "../controllers/posts.js";
const router = express.Router();

router.get("/", getPosts);

export default router;
```

**Packet.json:**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.4"
  }
}
```

**Error:** [Error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rp43B.png)

But when i used this statement: `export { getPosts };` , there where no error.

In ***packet.json*** I have added `"type": "module"`.

Can anyone explain when to use `export` and when `module.exports` ?

Comment: It is `module.exports`, NOT `module.export`

Comment: `module.export` is not the same as `module.exports`.

Comment: Even if I used `module.exports` it's still showing an error

Comment: @ReeKid “*an error*” is unfortunately not super helpful. *What* error? What is the stack trace? What does your code actually look like? [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yeah.  `module.exports` is not the same as `export`.  The two work a bit differently.  `module.exports` is used in a CommonJS module.  `export` is used in a ESM module.  `import` and `export` work well together in ESM modules.  `module.exports` and `require()` work well together in CommonJS modules.  There are some ways to achieve some combability between the two module types, but that is an advanced subject.  When possible, just use the same module type and matching syntax everywhere.

> In packet.json I have added `"type": "module"`.

That declares your top level entry point as an ESM module (where you would use `import` and `export`.

> Can anyone explain when to use `export` and when `module.exports`?

`export` is for ESM modules.  When you added `"type": "module"`, that made your module an ESM module and you should use `import` in that module to load other ESM module files.  And, in those other ESM module files, you should use `export` to declare what you want exported.

`module.exports` is for CommonJS modules (the older version of nodejs module).  Avoid mixing CommonJS and ESM modules whenever possible.  And, since you've declared `"type": "module"`, that whole directory will be treated as ESM module files by nodejs.